# Merging multiple columns as the table structure is written

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am trying to group multiple columns on my table by collapsing them into a single column and then use a UL list to separate the categories:

[image]

For this, what I am doing is adding a *boolean* to toggle the **start/stop stacking**, like this:

```
cols[0][0]="Name";
cols[0][1]=true; //<--toggler

cols[1][0]="Age";
cols[1][1]=false;

cols[2][0]="[M/F]";
cols[2][1]=false;

cols[3][0]="E-mail";
cols[3][1]=true;//<--toggler
```

However, using this method I have some problems:

1. I haven't managed to make two consecutive groups: [A]**[B+C][D+E]**[F]
2. the code is pretty hard to read, also to understand exactly what the toggle does

---

My code to write the **head** is the following:

```
document.writeln("<table><thead><tr>");

tmp = "<th>#";
flag = false;

for(i = 0; i < cols_len; i++){
    if(cols[i][1]){ //if stack-toggler
        if(flag){
            tmp += "</th><th>-";
        }

        flag = !flag;
    }

    if(!flag){
        tmp += "</th><th>" + cols[i][0];
    }
}

if(flag){
    tmp += "</th><th>-";
}

document.writeln(tmp + "</th></tr></thead><tbody>");
```

And then for the **body** of the table:

```
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){ //some number of rows
    if(i){
        document.writeln("</tr>");
    }

    document.writeln("<tr><td>" + i + "</td>");

    tmp = "";
    flag = false;

    for(j = 0; j < cols_len; j++){
        if(cols[j][1]){ //if stack-toggler
            if(flag){
                document.writeln("<td><ul>" + (tmp.replace(/<td/g, "<li").replace(/td>/g, "li>")) + "</ul></td>");
                tmp = "";
            }

            flag = !flag;
        }

        if(flag){
            tmp += "<strong>" + cols[j][0] + ":</strong><br>";
        }

        tmp += "<td>...</td>";

        if(!flag){
            document.writeln(tmp);

            tmp = "";
        }
    }

    if(flag){
        document.writeln("<td><ul>" + (tmp.replace(/<td/g, "<li").replace(/td>/g, "li>")) + "</ul></td>");
    }
}

document.writeln("</tr></tbody></table>");
```

**»The full code and demo [can be found in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qGfCB/).**

I feel this is the wrong approach, it sucks in every way and more importantly, **I can't have two or more consecutive groups**!, after I start stacking columns, whenever I want to stop, the next column must be alone (and not another group).

I have played around with the booleans and it is simply impossible, I can't figure it out, I already reduced the code to the most readable way and tried to rewrite parts of it but I keep getting the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a slight change to the data model.  Instead of "toggle" the boolean says if the next guy stacks or not (that is if it is true then put the next one below me.)

So the data looks like this:

```
/*0:caption, 1:stack-toggler*/
cols[0][0]="Name";
cols[0][1]=true; //<--stack next below

cols[1][0]="Age";
cols[1][1]=true; //<--stack next below

cols[2][0]="[M/F]";
cols[2][1]=false;

cols[3][0]="E-mail";
cols[3][1]=false; 

cols[4][0]="Website";
cols[4][1]=false;

cols[5][0]="Notes";
cols[5][1]=false;
```

And then the code can be simple -- like this (a trick I used, you can change the loop variable internal to the loop -- so we only loop on the outer loop when we change columns.)

```
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){ //some number of rows
    buildHTML("<tr><td>" + i + "</td>");

    for(j = 0; j < cols_len; j++){
        buildHTML("<td>");

        if (cols[j][1]) {
            buildHTML("<ul>"+cols[j][0]+"</ul>");

            // loop till we are at the penultimate 
            while (cols[j+1][1]) {
               j++;  
               buildHTML("<ul>"+cols[j][0]+"</ul>");
            }

            j++;                
            buildHTML("<ul>"+cols[j][0]+"</ul>");

        }
        else {
            buildHTML(cols[j][0]);
        }    
        buildHTML("</td>");
    }
    buildHTML("</tr>");
}

buildHTML("</tbody></table>");
```

I did not bother with the header, you can figure that out I'm sure.

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eajQy/3/

Of course with javascript you can get fancy.  Since what you really have is an array of arrays for the columns you could represent that like this:

```
// array of arrays -- one element std, 2 or more a list 
newcols = [ ["Name","Age","[M/F]"] , ["E-Mail"] , ["Website"], ["Notes"] ];
```

Then to make your table you could use map and join like this:

```
buildHTML("<tr><td>" + i + "</td>");

strArray = $.map(newcols, function (anArray) { 
   if (anArray.length == 1) {
      return "<td>"+anArray[0]+"</td>";
   } 
   else {
     return "<td><ul>"+anArray.join("</ul><ul>")+"</ul></td>";
   }
});

buildHTML(strArray.join(""));

buildHTML("</td></tr></tbody></table>");
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eajQy/4/

Single line solution (because every question should have a single line solution):

http://jsfiddle.net/eajQy/5/